# Pictured Depictions of Movie Quotes Misquoted

Tags: visual, rebus, movies

Self-explanatory, right? I'm looking for

> The **incorrect** quotation, as depicted by the pictures below.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5.

[image]

6.

[image]

Hint for #2:

> The line is from a famous '60s movie with Apes

Hint for #5:

> Australia has world's 2nd largest population of what?

****SPOILERS**** The intended answers:

> 1.There's no place like **NOME** 2. Get your filthy hands off me, you damn **GILBERT GRAPE** 3. You're gonna need a bigger **COAT** 4. Sometimes ya just gotta say 'What the **FLOCK**. 5. I *am*... in a world... of **SHEEP** 6. **BILSON!!!!**

Comment: (The solution is not part of the question and shouldn't be included in the question post. If you feel the need to post the full solution set yourself, please post it as a self-answer. In this particular case since you're really just collecting the correct answers from their respective answerers, some people suggest a CW post for this.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.

> "There's no place like <s>home</s> [Nome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome,_Alaska)." [[The Wizard of Oz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJ6VT7ciR1o)]

3.

> "You're gonna need a bigger <s>boat</s> coat." [[Jaws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT9BeGNnCqw) (with reference to [Tommy Boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYB3Fx0a8-4))]

Comment: Wow, these two answers fit like a glove.

Comment: Yes, @Phylyp, two down and four to go. +1

Answer (score 6):

My guess for number 6 is

> "WILSON!!" from Castaway. Somebody might have hit a volleyball toward her and would be shouting "Bilson!!" It would fit with the other answers, since it rhymes and there's only one letter changed. The volleyball seems to fit as well.

I know number 5 is from

> Pyle's death scene in Full Metal Jacket. I'm guessing the quote being changed might be "I am in a world of shit", but I'm not sure what it's changed to; maybe "I am in Australia" but that doesn't seem to fit too well. Hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: #6 is right, and #5 is right quote, but I had another thing in mind for the last word. (It doesn't really rhyme, either, see my comment on SwiftPanda's answer.)

Comment: Wilson is also a company that makes sporting goods such as volleyballs

Answer (score 4):

4 could be:

> "What the flock!" which is a misquote of Joel (Tom Cruise) from Risky Business.  I'm pretty sure everyone can figure out the actual quote ...

Partial for 6 (maybe it will help someone)

> The woman about to be hit is Rachel Bilson

Comment: Also, Bilson's breakout role was "Summer" on The O.C. which fits with the rest of the image.

Comment: Close enough on #4. In my mind, I always hear "Sometimes you just gotta say **** *** ****!"

Answer (score 3):

Based on the hint, #5 is

> I am in a world of sheep

Answer (score 2):

Picture 1 is

> "Toto, I have a feeling we're no longer in Alaska.

Comment: Right movie (*obvi !*), wrong scene. Try again?

Answer (score 2):

My guess for 5

> "I am in a world of *grit*" Rhymes with shit, sand is gritty, lots of sand in outback

Comment: Not what I intended. The answers don't have to rhyme. For example: @Pugmonkey has Tom Cruise's quote right, but it's not a real rhyme.

Answer (score 1):

Is #2 perhaps

> What's Eating Gilbert Ape?

As the main image seems to be a still from the movie

> What's Eating Gilbert Grape?

and then

> the character on the right has an ape's face laid over her own.

Comment: Close, but the answer won't be an incorrect movie *title,* it'll be an incorrect movie *quote.*